# How to remove My Pages and My Submissions from Liferay Control panel

Tags: liferay, customization, control-panel

I'm currently working on a Liferay project and want to get rid of the *My Pages* and *My Submissions* menu items on the right side so that users of my site do not bother with them. Tried looking for the jsp that renders the left side menu, but could manage to remove the item from there. Any ideas how to proceed? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

You could add the following lines to your *portal-ext.properties* (usually found in *webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes* under tomcat):

```
#deactivate Personal Community with *private* pages
layout.user.private.layouts.enabled=false 
#deactivate Personal Community with *public* pages
layout.user.public.layouts.enabled=false
#hide Personal Community from my places
my.places.show.community.private.sites.with.no.layouts=false
```

and **restart the server**.

Answer (score 0):

You probably rather want to limit the permissions to people. Don't give out global administration roles, but create your own roles, "Define Permissions" for them as you need them and leave out the permissions that you don't want to provide to your users - e.g. "access in control panel" or the general permission to add a page.

Otherwise you'll miss other ways to use the interface and still allow them to add pages through other means (e.g. "Manage/Page").

Edit: The easiest way to get rid of "My Submissions" is to undeploy the workflow plugin (kaleo-web) - of course you can only do this if you don't need workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same task assigned. Fortunately removing this items from the menu is quite straightforward since the control panel is nothing more than a special layout for displaying portlets that are deployed in the portal server. You can read my blog post [here](http://liferay.bdedov.eu/2012/02/clean-up-control-panel-from-unnecessary.html) to check the simple steps on how to customize the Control Panel and My Account portlet.

http://liferay.bdedov.eu/2012/02/clean-up-control-panel-from-unnecessary.html